# ANSYS Meshing Issue - How To Mesh Complicated Geometry (~80,000 Faces)?

Tags: mesh, fluent, ansys

I am attempting to mesh a complicated design (~80,000 faces) for a microchannel heat sink, as pictured, and I would appreciate some advice. I have tried a range of different mesh controls (especially face sizing and body sizing), mesh settings and element sizes, and all have failed to produce a working mesh. The most common errors are shown in the linked picture, in particular the one regarding "The following surfaces cannot be meshed with acceptable quality. Try using a different element size or virtual topology." However, I have already reduced the element size to 2x10^-6 m, which takes two days to resolve before failure.

Unfortunately I cannot alter the geometry significantly, as it is imported from generation in SolidWORKS as either a STEP or an x.t file. As such, any advice for how I can successfully mesh the geometry for CFD analysis in FLUENT would be greatly appreciated.

I can provide more details or the geometry file itself if required.

Thanks in advance.

[Meshing Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU3VM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. In the end I solved the issue by importing the original mesh generated by COMSOL into SpaceClaim, then employing both the "Smooth" and "Reduce Faces" tools in tandem to simplify the geometry, before finally using SolidWORKS to turn the smoothed mesh into a solid body. This body retained many of the same features as the original, but was much less complex, having two orders of magnitude fewer faces. In turn, this permitted both meshing and heat transfer analysis in FLUENT.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your cad design is not clean at all. But it is impossible to notice from this image. If you don't have control over the geometry source it is trouble. Because you might ask somebody else about check and fix something. First check you can do with your model it's trying to reduce the number of elements until the minimum possible value. Then if the mesh runs properly you can relay in the surfaces of your cad model. After that, you can refine the mesh, but the refining process is something that you have to do following some error criteria. If you are also the designer why not try to simplify a bit the geometry if you consider it is really hard to mesh? Meshing properly is a hard task, you should go step-by-step until you reach some solution. Also, you must not allow the preprocessor mesh automatically, without giving some criteria. Probably the first thing you have to answer even before apply any mesh is, what is your Reynolds number? And what is the most valuable result in which you can base the goodness of your discretization?